# DSpace XMLUI Batch-Importer: Import fails (No such file or directory) / Error: Permission denied

Tags: dspace

So when i try to upload the zip file without changing the data sometimes it works and sometimes it does not, i get the following errors with the same data input:

ERROR org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport @ AddItems encountered an error, will try to revert. Error: Permission denied      ---> weird thing is sometimes it goes through and other times i get this issue.
Which leaves me at a loss, permissions and everything was checked.

Has anyone had this issue?

OS : Ubuntu
Application : Dspace
Module : Import Batch Load (ZIP)

Answer (score 0):

Too bad it doesn't say *where* permission was denied.  But my first guess would be:  look through the assetstore directory tree for directories that are owned by some account other than the one that runs DSpace -- for example, root.  Running the command-line ingestion tools as a different user can cause such issues, because this will create any necessary new directories with the wrong ownership.

Comment: The weird thing is if i upload eg: zip1 , gives me the issue. if i try again with no changes later or a couple times it works , which is strange. i have checked the ownership of the asset store and its owned by "dspace tomcat7" the whole folder which causes me to be at a loss